# MYSQL: two tables and expected results

Tags: mysql

I've two tables , Table 1 has unique ids and referrer , table 2 contain some unique ids from table 1

**Table 1**

```
uniqueid    | Referrer   
------------------------
abcd1234    | google.com  
27316dsh    | google.com
37283667    | yahoo.com
3728ydhu    | yahoo.com
362ydhhd    | example.com
23819377    | google.com
223hd782    | google.com
2372jdyh    | yahoo.com
qewe7182    | test.com
```

**Table 2:**

```
uniqueid    
------------
abcd1234    
27316dsh    
37283667    
3728ydhu    
362ydhhd
```

**Expected result**

```
Referrer    | Total Referrer | Referrer present in table 2 | Percent
--------------------
google.com  |  4             | 2                           | 50%
yahoo.com   |  3             | 2                           | 66% 
example.com |  1             | 1                           | 100%
test.com    |  1             | 0                           | 0%
```

What SQL Query should I use to have the expected result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `LEFT` join of `table1` to `table2` and aggregation:

```
select t1.referrer,
       count(*) `Total Referrer`,
       count(t2.uniqueid) `Referrer present in table 2`,
       concat(round(100.0 * count(t2.uniqueid) / count(*)), '%') Percent 
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on t2.uniqueid = t1.uniqueid
group by t1.referrer
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cgnkDzygNrU9ai4ecQk6Gz/1).
Results:

```
| referrer    | Total Referrer | Referrer present in table 2 | Percent |
| ----------- | -------------- | --------------------------- | ------- |
| example.com | 1              | 1                           | 100%    |
| google.com  | 4              | 2                           | 50%     |
| test.com    | 1              | 0                           | 0%      |
| yahoo.com   | 3              | 2                           | 67%     |
```